# MySql finding the total count after a group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to find out the count of people who have rented from 2 stores.

THe schema is as below.

```
Rental table
----------------------------------------------------
rental_id   int(11) NO  PRI 
rental_date datetime    NO  MUL 
inventory_id    mediumint(8) unsigned   NO  MUL 
customer_id smallint(5) unsigned    NO  MUL 
return_date datetime    YES     
staff_id    tinyint(3) unsigned NO  MUL 
last_update timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP


Inventory table
---------------------------------------------------
inventory_id    mediumint(8) unsigned   NO  PRI 
film_id smallint(5) unsigned    NO  MUL 
store_id    tinyint(3) unsigned NO  MUL 
last_update timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

With this query I can get the list of customers who rented from 2 stores.

```
select customer_id 
  from rental r
      , inventory i 
  where r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id 
  group 
     by customer_id 
 having count(distinct i.store_id) = 2;
```

How to find the count as a part of the same sql statement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select count(*) from(
    select customer_id 
    from rental r , inventory i 
    where r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id 
    group by customer_id 
    having count(distinct i.store_id) = 2);
```

You will have to aggregate you results in the inner query for that matter, So u'll have to rap the query with another one that will count all the results.

Answer (score 0):

You would use two aggregations.  The first gets the people who have rented from two stores.  The second adds them up.  So:

```
select count(*)
from (select r.customer_id
      from rental r join
           inventory i
           on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
      group by r.customer_id
      having count(distinct i.store_id) = 2
     ) r;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select r.customer_id, count(*) 
from rental r
join inventory i 
on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id 
where i.store_id = 2
group by r.customer_id
```